# Interchangeable menu in Scala Play

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

At the moment I'm developing a web application using Bootstrap and Scala Play and I don't really understand the templating engine.

I would like to have different Bootstrap navbars. The first one, if the user is not logged in yet.
[image: user not logged in yet]

And a second view, when the user is logged in where he/she can see her name on the top right corner of the navbar.

Therefore I created a **loginMenu.scala.html file**, to make the right side of the navbar interchangeable

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                Login
        <strong class="caret"></strong>
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu login-menu" role="menu">
        <form class="form-horizontal" action="@routes.Authentication.authenticate" method="post">

            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="email" name="email" id="email">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password" name="password", id="password">
            <label class="checkbox" style="padding-top:0px">
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="1"> Remember me
            </label>

            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</li>
```

I then try to insert it dynamically in my navigation bar template **main.scala.html**

```
@(title: String, currentPage: String)(rightMenu: Html)(content: Html)

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>@title</title>
        ...
    </head>
<!-- Bootstrap navbar here-->
...
<!--right side of Bootstrap nav -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
             @rightMenu
       </ul>
 </div>
```

In my other sites I use something like this:

```
@main("Welcome to Play", "Home") (@loginMenu){
   <div class="container">
       <h2>Home</h2>
   </div>
}
```

When I try to start it, I get the following errors.

```
[error]home.scala.html:3: missing arguments for method apply in object main;
[error] follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function

[error] @main("Welcome to Play", "Home") (@loginMenu){ 
             ^
```

I simply want @loginMenu to print the raw HTML in my current file. How do I do this?

Comment: If you're applying `loginMenu` as an argument to `main` you don't need the `@` in front of it, since you're already in a Scala code block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're applying `loginMenu` as an argument to `main` you don't need the `@` in front of it, since you're already in a Scala code block.

Try:

```
@main("Welcome to Play", "Home")(loginMenu()) {
    <div class="container">
       <h2>Home</h2>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: If you do it like that, you get a type mismatch:
found   : views.html.loggedInMenu.type
              required: play.twirl.api.Html

I figured out that you have to call loginMenu.apply() to get the HTML

Answer (score 2):

I think you are almost there

```
@main("Welcome to Play", "Home") {@loginMenu()}  {
                                 ^          ^^^
                                 ^          ^^^
   <div class="container">
       <h2>Home</h2>
   </div>
}
```

Watch it for `curly braces` and `circular braces` if you are passing `Html`

Or with round brackets:

```
@main("Welcome to Play", "Home")(loggedInMenu.apply()) {...}
```

**Pay attention not to put a white space between** 
`("Welcome to Play", "Home")` and `(loggedInMenu.apply())`. Otherwise it will not work.